# How to plot multifactorial function?

Tags: plotting, function-construction, warning-messages, special-functions, products

The [multifactorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778550/how-to-evaluate-the-limit-of-multifactorial-lim-n-to-0-sqrtnn-cdots/4029044?noredirect=1#comment8319381_4029044) function can be extended to the reals (see `TheSimpliFire` answer) like so:

> It follows that we can extend the multifactorial function to the reals through
>
> $$x!^{(k)}=k^{x/k}\Gamma\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(\frac{i k^{-i/k}}{\Gamma(1+i/k)}\right)^{\sin(\pi(x-i))\cot(\pi(x-i)/k)/k}$$

```
Multifactorial[x_, k_] := k^(x/k)*Gamma[1 + x/k]*
Product[((j k^(-(j/k)))/Gamma[(j + k)/k])^(1/k*Sin[Pi (x - j)] Cot[Pi*(x - j)/k]),
        {j, 1, k - 1}]

Multifactorial[2, 5]
(*Error messages: "Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered"*)

Plot[Multifactorial[x, 5], {x, -4, 4}]
```

How can get to work and [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lltwcgps6j) (with `Desmos`, it works fine) the function?

Comment: Note that `Cot[π (-j + z)] Sin[π (-j + z)]` simplifies to `Cos[π (-j + z)]`

Comment: @J.M. See my updated question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The immediate cure is to instead use the Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind, $U_n(x)$, in the definition:

```
multiFactorial[x_, k_] := k^(x/k) Gamma[1 + x/k] Product[((j k^(-(j/k)))/Gamma[(j + k)/k])^
                                                         (Cos[(π (-j + x))/k]/k
                                                          ChebyshevU[k - 1, Cos[(π (-j + x))/k]]),
                                                         {j, 1, k - 1}]
```

For instance:

```
multiFactorial[x, 2] - x!! // FunctionExpand // Simplify
   0

Plot[multiFactorial[x, 5], {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image: plot of 5-factorial]

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)
```

Treat the case for integer `x` as a limit.

**Edited to match revised question**

```
Multifactorial[x_Integer, k_Integer?Positive] := Module[{z},
  Limit[k^(z/k)*Gamma[1 + z/k]*
    Product[((j k^(-(j/k)))/Gamma[(j + k)/k])^(1/k*
        Sin[Pi (z - j)] Cot[Pi*(z - j)/k]), {j, 1, k - 1}], z -> x]]

Multifactorial[x_, k_Integer?Positive] := 
 k^(x/k)*Gamma[1 + x/k]*
  Product[((j k^(-(j/k)))/Gamma[(j + k)/k])^(1/k*
      Sin[Pi (x - j)] Cot[Pi*(x - j)/k]), {j, 1, k - 1}]

Multifactorial[2, 5]

(* 2 *)

Multifactorial[2 - 10^-10, 5] // N

(* 2. *)

Multifactorial[2 + 10^-10, 5] // N

(* 2. *)

Show[
 Plot[Multifactorial[x, 5], {x, -4, 4}],
 DiscretePlot[Multifactorial[x, 5], {x, -4, 4}]]
```

[image]

There are still issues if you enter an integer as a real, e.g.,

```
Multifactorial[2., 5]

(* Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.

Indeterminate *)
```

However, you can resolve this by rationalizing the input.

```
Multifactorial[2. // Rationalize, 5]

(* 2 *)
```

Comment: I made a mistake.I'm update my question.Power in product is: `1/k*Sin[Pi (x - j)] Cot[Pi*(x - j)/k]` not: `Sin[Pi (x - j)] Cot[Pi*(x - j)]`.